# In Cocoa/OSX, how to detect which type (LAN, WiFi, etc...) of internet connection is active?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, wifi, ethernet

Simple question, that is giving me some headaches... In the context of Cocoa/OSX framework. Suppose you have both WiFi and ethernet/board internet connections. How to detect which of them is the active one?

Comment: Note that they can both be active at the same time, so it's not an either/or. It's also possible to have multiple network interfaces, e.g. 2 x Ethernet, 1 x WiFi, 1 x VPN, 1 x Bluetooth, etc.

Comment: Well.. sorry for this broadness. Let me put it better: how can I find which connection is about to be used, when I'm accessing a remote service (i.e. web-service)?

Comment: OK - I'm not sure that you can - the interface can change dynamically - but I'm not an expert on this, so there may be a way - good luck...

Comment: Thank you Paul. I think I can do this because the connection can't hang/switch between interfaces at connection's moment. By switching interfaces, the IP also change, and the connection should be restarted/reconfigured on the application socket perspective. Isn't it?

Comment: Look at this [SCNetworkReachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: [Utility on network reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)